# "Cannot load file or assembly" - Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, dll

I have a project targeting .Net 6.0 framework and I am trying to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel as I would like to run an excel macro configured inside the .xlsm file that exists on the same local system.
Regarding Excel version - I am running Microsoft 365 (I am not sure how this translates into Excel versions that used to be more explicit in the naming earlier).
The error that I have when running my code is shown here: 
[image: 1]

This is the code where the problem occurs (last line basically):

```
void RunMacro(string macroFilename)
{
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
   
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(macroFilename);
    xlApp.Visible = true;

    xlApp.Run("Main");
}
```

For including Interop.Excel package in the project, I tried to install it as a NuGet package, so in that case the project file looks like this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetCore.NPOI" Version="1.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExcelDataReader" Version="3.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExcelDataReader.DataSet" Version="3.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" Version="15.0.4795.1001" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Alternatively, I tried to refer to the interop dll using the "Add project reference" option, so here is how the project file looks in that case:

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetCore.NPOI" Version="1.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExcelDataReader" Version="3.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExcelDataReader.DataSet" Version="3.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

However, in the end, the error from the screenshot remains in both cases. What could be causing this? Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: I've seen Nuget packages that get this badly wrong, presumably you are using one of them.  You always get *two* dependencies if you target Excel, highly recommended that you do this through the COM tab so you can be sure you get a version that is compatible with the flavor of Excel that you have installed on your machine.  Those packages only supply Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and forgot that you also need office.dll.  There is a Nuget package for it as well, but do favor the COM tab.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I don't know origin of this solution, but I removed nuget package reference and replace it with this COMReference shippet in the .csproj file.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel">
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <VersionMinor>9</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>00020813-0000-0000-c000-000000000046</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
    <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Core">
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <VersionMinor>8</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>2</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>2df8d04c-5bfa-101b-bde5-00aa0044de52</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: thank you so much for this answer.  this solved my problem.  the nuget package gave error, but this com ref solved it.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have corresponding version of Office installed. It means for Interop version 15.0.0.0 you should have Office 2013 and other versions of Office will not work.